# Unable to filter array with three arrays inside of it in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, filter

I know the title might sound a bit tricky but I've something like this: `[['potato', 'tomato', 'strawberry'], ['franco', 'elisabeth', 'alfred'], ['eat', 'sleep', 'code']]` and I need to filter it according to the value of my v-model.

I'll try to be more specific right now:

In my Vuex store i've this:

```
actions: {
    // ---------------COMUNAS----------- //
    // Trae el listado de comunas
    getCommunes: async function ({ commit }) {
      const communes = await PostService.getPosts();
      let perChunk = 4 // items per chunk    
      let inputArray = communes;
      const results = inputArray.reduce((resultArray, item, index) => { 
        const chunkIndex = Math.floor(index/perChunk)
        if(!resultArray[chunkIndex]) {
          resultArray[chunkIndex] = [] // start a new chunk
        }
        resultArray[chunkIndex].push(item)
        return resultArray
      }, [])
      commit('obtainCommunes', { communes, results });
    },
```

So in my Vue component:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      communeFilter: '',
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapState(['communes', 'results']),
    filteredCommunes() {
      if(this.communeFilter === '') {
        return this.result;
      } else {
        return this.result.filter(a => 
          a.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.communeFilter.toLowerCase()) ||
          a.description.toLowerCase().includes(this.communeFilter.toLowerCase())
        )
      }
    },
  },
}
```

Now my HTML in the very same Vue component:

```
<div class="columns" v-for='(result, index) in results' :key='index'>
        <div class="column is-3 is-column-commune" v-for='(commune, index) in result' :key='index'>
          <div class="card mb-6" @click='goToCommune(commune.id)'>
            <div class="card-image">
              <figure class="image is-3by2">
                <img :src="commune.image">
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <div class="media">
                <div class="media-content has-text-centered">
                  <p class="title is-4">{{ commune.name }}</p>
                  <p class="subtitle is-6">{{ commune.description }}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This tricky thing was needed because I wanted to show 4 cards per row and iterating without that wasn't solving my problem.

One more time: I simply need to filter the array according to communeFilter value. Of course I already used my `filteredCommunes()` in the `v-for` but it didn't work as expected.

I hope someone could help me because I've been stucked on this by the past 2 days and I'm beggining to feel a bit frustrated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Even though I didn't understand the whole question, let me try to simplify and I hope that simplified version helps you solve your issue.

I assume the following:

```js
// results = [['potato', 'tomato', 'strawberry'], ['franco', 'elisabeth', 'alfred'], ['eat', 'sleep', 'code']]

// this.communeFilter has value 'pota' which is partial of 'potato'

// assuming the above, we can write the 'filteredCommunes' as follows
filteredCommunes () {
    if (this.communeFilter === '') {
        return this.results
    }

    return this.results.filter(a => {
        return a.filter(s => return s && s.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.communeFilter.toLowerCase()) > -1).length > 0;
    })
}

// output of filteredCommunes() will return
// [["potato", "tomato", "strawberry"]]
// because the first item contains the value of this.communeFilter
```

I hope this is how you intended filteredCommunes to behave.